# Google AssistantでAccount Linkingを動作させようとしたところ、OAuth認証でエラー発生

Tags: google-cloud

Google AssistantでGoogleアカウント情報を取得するために、以下URLを参考にAccount Linkingを動作させようとしています。

https://qiita.com/flatfisher/items/1f39de99728d8717c73b

**Actions on Google Overviewの編集**
のOauth認証で
・Authorization URL
 　    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
を設定したところ、
Google accounts cannot be used as Auth endpoint urls per our Account Linking policy
のエラーが発生しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

対処方法について、ご存知の方いましたら回答お願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

初めまして。
私もこのエラーに悩まされました。

解決法についてですが、以下の記事の一番最後に記載されています。
https://discuss.api.ai/t/user-email-with-google-actions/12896/10

方法としては、一度他のAuthorization URL
（yahooのAuthorization URLなど適当でいいです。URL:http://d.hatena.ne.jp/ritou/20090712/1247338807）
を入力して、Saveします。
その後、本来のURLに書き換えてSaveし直すと上手くいくようです。

上手くいくことを願ってます。